# PowerBI - Sum of rows of one column based on criteria

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have what I think is pretty simple requirement - but having trouble implementing.  Basically I have two tables - with a 1:M relationship on the Name field

Log-Ins Table

| ID | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| login1 | Evan | March |
| login2 | Evan | March |
| login3 | Ryan | March |
| login4 | Ryan | March |
| login5 | Jack | March |
| login6 | Mike | March |
| login7 | Mike | April |
| login8 | Mike | April |
| login9 | Mike | April |
| login10 | Evan | April |
| login11 | Evan | April |

Contact Table

| Name | FamilyMembers |
| --- | --- |
| Evan | 3 |
| Ryan | 2 |
| Mike | 4 |
| Jack | 1 |

I want a report that totals the family members based on a log in - but I only want to count them once - using the Date as a slicer.  I created a measure called LoginCount which gives me a view that looks like this:

`LoginCount = COUNTROWS(RELATEDTABLE('Log-Ins'))`

What I'm looking for is the total of FamilyMembers (which when slicer is set to March should be 10)

| Name | LoginCount | FamilyMembers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Evan | 2 | 3 |
| Jack | 1 | 1 |
| Mike | 1 | 4 |
| Ryan | 2 | 2 |
|  | 6 |  |

and in April should be 7.

Closest I can get is to summarize the FamilyMembers Column - but it gives the total for each log-in (Evan h as 2 logins and 3 family members, which equals six) which I don't want.  The idea is to get a general headcount of serviced users for the month and not re-count the family members each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to rely on how the filters are propagating from one table to another.
If you apply `CROSSFILTER` you can solve this issue without changing the type of your relationship.

In others words, `Log-Ins` will filter the `Contacts` table.

### Calculation: Measure

```
Total Family Members =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Contacts[FamilyMembers] ),
    CROSSFILTER ( Contacts[Name], 'Log-Ins'[Name], BOTH )
)
```

### Output

[image]

### Relationship

[image]

Comment: ah crossfilter!!  That worked perfect.  I have another question regarding trending who is a new log in when compared to the previous month (tracking new people) but I'll make a new post for that as  this question is answered.